# how to align md-list-avatar with md-list-icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

angular material md-list https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview

The icon and the img don't align below, see the text yes and no don't line up, is this a bug? what's the easiest fix?:

```
<md-list>
  <h3 md-subheader>Folders</h3>
  <md-list-item>
    <img mdListAvatar src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
    <h4 md-line>yes</h4>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item>
    <md-icon md-list-icon>folder</md-icon>
    <h4 md-line>no</h4>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/cM6bD44kteOhOJZMB5G6?p=preview

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current solution is to just download the icon as an SVG and use at as an avatar - although they are a little big

```
<img src="/assets/ic_people_black_24px.svg" md-list-avatar>
```